# How do you ignore parts of a URL with Mod Rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using `Mod Rewrite` to create attractive URLs. I am trying to understand how it is possible to ignore parts of a URL?

For example, my original URL was:
`/file.php?token=771736eb78bc3b6f96d5c066069567c0c219bf65/`

And I have written a Mod Rewrite code to turn that into:
`/file/771736eb78bc3b6f96d5c066069567c0c219bf65/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)$ /file.php?token=$1 [L]
```

However, I would like to achieve a URL like:
`/file/771736eb78bc3b6f96d5c066069567c0c219bf65/random-bits-here/`

The random bits on the end serve no purpose (other than decoration). How do I tell Mod Rewrite to ignore this part of the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tweak your regex like this

```
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /file.php?token=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the second group of characters to your RewriteRule and ignore the caught expression, if you don't need it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /file.php?token=$1 [L]
```

Or, if you would like to have it passed to your script.:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /file.php?token=$1&extra=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply leave out the `$` sign, which forces the end of the string (path):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*) /file.php?token=$1 [L]
```